# populating ngoption with firebase list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

```
My Data Structure
    > ert123:{

    > groupMembers:{

    > CnpwzwPV6DaoikRXtNaTVTEHvZt1: "eee123",

    > hE9JONc5eVNsldRe9NOoM1HnpCf2: "fff123"

    >},

> groupOwner: "eee123",

> groupQuantity: 2

>}
```

Now I wish to populate the ionic select which uses ng-options to get from the firebase.

in my js file,

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('groups/'+ $rootScope.groupCode +'/groupMembers');
$scope.users = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

in my HTML file,

```
<select ng-model="handler" ng-options="user for user in users">
 </select>
```

How do i populate the values of each object in groupMembers into the ionic select?

Answer (score 0):

You are close if you tring to show users(accordinng to your code) data....

```
<select ng-model="handler" ng-options="user.userProperty for user in users track by user.$id">
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my results:

`<select ng-model="handler" ng-options="user.$value for user in users">
 </select>`

Thx Zaid for your answer. It inspires me!